# Could astronauts jump from a spaceship onto a spacestation and how would it be like if yes?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, orbit, spacecraft, interstellar-travel, rendezvous

I saw it happen in the videogame Alien:Isolation but not sure how realistic it was. I need help understanding some orbital mechanics for a sci-fi story that I am trying to write.

The scenario I imagine that there is a space-station, orbiting a celestial object.

A crew, with a 2 and a half meters high robot that is able to "leap", and two "astronauts" who would ride this robot would attempt to approach with their spaceship, and jump from the spaceship's airlock to the emergency airlock door of the space station.

Is this possible? Would the spaceship need to go next to the station and go on the same trajectory with the same speed, or would it need to move slightly faster than the space station at the time of the jump?

As a reference here is the scene from the videogame:

This however does not let one see (or I do not see) how the spaceship was behaving relative to the station.

Comment: This is not a good question for this site. Consider asking it on worldbuilding. Space stations orbiting black holes are purely fictional.

Comment: Well but the point of my question has nothing to do with the black hole, but with the jump itself. There is an object orbiting a celestial body. We can switch up the black hole with Earth, if that would help. Is the jump possible then? By aligning speed with the oribiting object, or by being faster than it?

Comment: You have an interesting question here and I strongly recommend that *you do not accept* the first, short, dismissive answer about the black hole. Give it a few days at  least to give others a chance to give it some thought, add some comments and hopefully some much more helpful answers. *Welcome to Stack Exchange!*

Comment: Yeah, well I am writing a sci-fi that is in the far future where there are technologies like warpdrive and energy-shields, if that helps. Maybe I was just too specific with my question. What I need to know is how a jump from a spaceship to a station in orbit could (if could) happen? Would it require the spaceship to align it's speed with the station, or would the spaceship need to do an approaching maneouver, moving slightly faster than the station?

Comment: It will help get answers here if the scope of the question (not your story) is current or near-future technology and objects we are likely to visit in the not-so-distant future. So while I've made some edits to your question already I think you can simply drop the reference to the black hole completely.

Comment: Okay, thanks, did the edits. Sorry Im new to this site and everything, just decided I want some level of realism into my writing and did not find an proper answer simply by using google search.

Comment: I now also included a video of the scene from the videogame.

Comment: Surely where it goes depends on the orientation of the station, the ship and the airlocks. Bit like choosing (if you could) which docking port to go to on the ISS, assuming you had a multi-universal-port-adapter on your spacecraft. Which port you go dictates your flight plan.

Comment: Definitely doable, but there are very many variables about the jump that remain to be defined in order to arrive at a "probability of possibility".  One of the primary variables is, of course, distance between points. I'd surmise that any jump over 15 meters would require some sort of course correction ability to hit close to a doorway. In an 'on orbit' condition there are 5 relative position possibilities that make the jump easier or harder. Is the ship (1) leading or (2) trailing the station? Is the ship (3) 'above' or (4) 'below' the station. Is the ship (5) beside the station.

Comment: lets assume zero relative velocity for all 5 conditions.   Each of these have very different orbital mechanics and require very different trajectories if the distance is not trivial.           An 'on orbit' jump is very much more complicated than a 'deep space' jump.

Comment: Well I wanted to be less specific because I thought  I was too specific first, but I'd say ten meters and the ship was to be beside the station. Part of my question is wether it is doable if the ship has zero relative velocity or if it has to speed up in order to allow for the jump to succeed? Also there are nuzzles on the robot to correct trajectory and also provide a bit of speed. Like a jetpack on an astronaut I assume.

Comment: Whats the orientation of the station? Is it much like the ISS now or is it very different?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by orientation but if we go with what is in my writing it is on high orbit and a more complex and bigger construct,. Somthing like this except no outer platforms like that but spherical moduls. It has a hangar for spaceships but on the opposite side the spaceship approaches, and it would be too dangerous to try and get to that side, that is why they are to go in through an emergency airlock.

Comment: The reason I would like to make is o that they are jumping is that since in my story it orbits a black hole, if they add more weight or a push through connecting their spaceship it could "tip it over" closer towards the accretion disc and the event horizon. It hangs in a balance...

Comment: I want to know more about the nuzzles. Is it a really cuddly robot?

Comment: Hahaha funny yeah

Comment: I think I would only find https://i.imgur.com/Ex9sIZR.jpg cuddly if I was the one wrapped up in oodles of cotton wool and bubble wrap... TBH I kept thinking of two movies: 2010 and the transfer over to Discovery and Sunshine where antagonist literally leapt over to the other ship (In pre-production I recall sending everything I had on the current projects over as they wanted at least the ships to be 'realistic')

Answer (score 2):

It is not mandatory that the two vessels have zero relative velocity, but it would make the operation more controlled (and therefore less exciting). Having vessels in close proximity with significant relative velocity risks collision so would only be likely in uncontrolled or emergency conditions. If your scenario involves relative velocity, the jump transfer is still possible.

There is no theoretical limit to the distance that could be “jumped”, but a long jump would affect the precision (and the chance of successful) arrival.

One big challenge would be rotation during transit, with an uncontrolled attitude on arrival. It would be very difficult to jump without imparting at least a small angular momentum. If you arrive butt-first after a 180* pitch/yaw, you will find yourself disoriented and unable to grab on.

Another issue is that you will all arrive with the same kinetic energy and momentum as when you departed. Just like 3 billiard balls, all heading into a corner cushion. Unless each character is face-forward and latches onto a hand-hold first attempt, someone is going to bounce off into the blackness. Plan to write one character out of the story.

One happy thought is that you can ignore complicated orbital mechanics as it applies to orbital rendezvous: that "back up to catch up" stuff. Because the jump will last only a vey small orbital phase angle, it will not apply.

So, to answer your question, YES. "It is possible. But not recommended" as they said in Red October.

Comment: OP says that 2 are riding on 1, so perhaps all three billiard balls have a string to each other..  so that should save the one bouncing off into to the inky blackness.

Comment: @blobbymcblobby ---- A wise strategy to string everyone together. That gives a better chance that at least one will grab on. But I think the line should break and one spin off like Frank Poole. It should be the character that everyone expected to be The Savior. Stephen King always kills The Savior 2/3 of the way through.

Comment: I like it. Can't always have a happy ending!

Comment: I can't find the quote [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PiN2OrKPfU) but still "hunting" for it

Comment: @blobbymcblobby ---- Oh-oh-oh! Another twist: They miss the critical grab. It looks like they are all gonna die! Then the line crosses a strut and they all whip around it like a bolo. One character's carabiner snaps and he cartwheels off into the void !!! An oxygen hose starts leaking and there is a race to the airlock! Sound-over of heartbeats and gasping breath !!! The airlock slams shut and character is saved by defibrilation with a sparking electrical cable !!!

Comment: @Oh-oh ---- Sean Connery asks if he can have 110% on reactor power. The Watch Officer says ,"110% possible, but not recommended".

Comment: found it! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZB3ZclZtZg&t=33s  or at least one instance of it, but this one isn't Connery's scene It may not be all of them, it's... *one ping only*

Comment: @Oh-oh ----- Oops. Wrong submarine, Wrong commander. Wrong reactor power. But I got the movie right.

Comment: @Woody - also got uhoh's name wrong lol Love that movie though. I hope OP is taking notes for his re-write! :P

Comment: "It is not mandatory that the two vessels have zero relative velocity, but it would make the operation more controlled (and therefore less exciting).": actually, it may well be more controlled to have the ship "throw" them (and then maneuver to prevent collision) than attempt to hit the right trajectory by jumping. However, any survivable encounter velocity will be only a hairs breadth from "zero" considering more typical relative velocities.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff ----You first. I'll hold your beer.

Comment: This is a sci-fi playing in the far future. The robot will not get disoriented, because it is a robot with an AI. It also can latch onto anything easily because it has big "claws.". By the robot imagine something like this: https://i.imgur.com/Ex9sIZR.jpg
 It also has an energy shield, and also the passenger's clothing is a suit from around 4000 AD. Hyper advanced, as in it has life support systems, and also electromagnets to help keep themselfs on the robot's back. 
All I needed to know is how it is optimal to approach and jump if possible. I do not think there is other option. No docking.

Comment: If docking is too risky, only jump left right? Or what other option to get from the spaceship onto the space station, without tipping the balance of the station's orbit, risking that it would fall into the black hole. I wanted it to be "not recommended", this is supposed to be a risky undertaking by the characters.

Comment: The phisics are what I do not think I completely understand here because if they move with relative zero velocity to each other, when the passengers jump, would not they "miss" the spacestation by it moving forward while they jump? Or they would naturally jump with a curve towards the station? Phisics laws like that are not exactly clear to me. Would they need to use nozzles to go in such  curve?

Answer (score 1):

To me the term jump is defined as a phsyical movement that implies a somewhat impulsive force acting against gravity to move an object and then subsequently the object returns to a datum plane under the return influence of gravity.  A lateral velocity component could be included so the return point is at some distance from the starting point. In the strictist sense of this definition "jumping" as defined above from one spacecraft in zero gravity to another cannot be done.

But a body could be propelled using one's own force to an adjacent body in zero gravity.  It is advisable to have a restraint cord attached to the other body. It is also advisible to aim precisely. Also, I would not consider this maneuver over a very long distance.

Fun question,    tom kosvic

Comment: This is an odd definition of jump. Jumping covers almost any motive push with the legs, and does not require gravity, or that you come back down. By this logic, leaping upward and grabbing a bar overhead isn't a jump, nor is leaping into space from a low-gravity planetoid, nor is pushing off the wall of a rotating space station with your legs. I'd say pretty much any movement with the legs that moves you in the direction of your head is a jump.

Comment: Per miriam webster definition of jump,
1a: to spring into the air : LEAP
especially : to spring free from the ground or other base by the muscular action of feet and legs.  That would also imply that gravity returns you to ground, i.e., "what goes up must come down" in common parlance.     Enough fun on definition of jump